# Python pandas - merging a table with itself

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks conceptually like this:

```
ID   SUM    Stime    Etime    
 3   10.0 18:00:00 18:09:59
 2   12.0 18:15:00 18:26:59
 3   3.0  18:36:00 18:38:59
 4   3.0  18:36:00 18:38:59
 5   59.0 18:00:00 18:58:59
 12  10.0 17:00:00 17:09:59
 12  16.0 18:24:00 18:39:59
 7   16.0 18:24:00 18:39:59
 8   19.0 18:40:00 18:58:59
 12  19.0 18:40:00 18:58:59
 10  19.0 18:40:00 18:58:59
 11  3.0  18:03:00 18:05:59
 12  11.0 18:59:00 18:09:59
```

Stime and Etime cols are from type datetime.

SUM is the number of minutes between Stime and Etime.

What I need to do is to update the table such that if, for a certain person (ID), the Stime comes right after the end time - I will unit the 2 lines and I will update SUM.

For example here, for `ID=12` the first Etime is `18:39:59`
and the second Stime is `18:40:00` - which comes right after 18:39:59,  and also the second Etime is `18:58:59` and the third Stime is `18:59:00`- which comes right after 18:58:59 - so I would like to unit the 3 lines and update SUM for this person to be `46` (16+19+11).

I tried to use `merge` - but the problem with that is that it is merging correctly just 2 lines and not 3 or more.

Comment: You need to groupby by 'ID' and sum the Etime-Stime difference. Only after that you can join with the original df.

Comment: but I want to sum them only if the times are consecutive. for example here I don't want to sum the first record of `ID=12` cause it is not consecutive with the other records.

Answer (score 0):

Beni - apologies as I don't have the reputation to comment. I'm pretty sure I have answered your previous question which should avoid the need for a solution here: [Python Pandas - combining 2 lines from data frame - with condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37467146/python-pandas-combining-2-lines-from-data-frame-with-condition/37514169#37514169)

Can you review that please and I will get back to you if its not appropriate?

Comment: Hi, and thank you for the effort. your solution is close, but the `Stime` and `Etime` are not updated. for example: 
`1220760  A  35  18:40:00  18:58:59`  - the `C` col is right, but the `Etime` and `Stime` are not, also, I'm looking for something a bit more elegant , there should be a function that computes it in 1-5 lines.

Comment: That's because you never specified that Stime and Etime should be updated with the row, only that C should be. How do you need Stime and Etime to be updated?

Comment: C is the difference between Stime and Etime, so they need to be updated according to `C` value (like UNTUBU's solution).

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {'ID' : [1, 2, 3,12, 4,12,5,12],'SUM' : [4, 3, 2, 16,1,19,2,11]}
df =pd.DataFrame(d)
>>> df
    ID  SUM
0   1    4
1   2    3
2   3    2
3  12   16
4   4    1
5  12   19
6   5    2
7  12   11

df.groupby(['ID']).sum()


    SUM
ID     
1     4
2     3
3     2
4     1
5     2
12   46
```

Comment: That is not what I'm after... you should sum just if the times are consecutive. for `ID=12` you should ignore the first record, as I explained.